# How can I view html from the node console?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, user-interface

I have a javascript code that dumps an object, downloaded it from https://github.com/johan/node-dump.

Unfortunately, it prints an HTML, which is not very helpful, since I am working from the node console. How can I send this html output to some HTML rendering engine to display it visually? This could be a browser or a node plugin capable to display HTML snippets in a window.

I am on Windows 7.

**EDIT**

Guys, I do not need to beautify html. I want to render it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using console.log() or console.dir() to print your object in the console in a human-readable format?

Comment: Deleted the mentioning of "non human friendly". The HTML in itself is not very useful to me. I want to see what it has to say visually, rather than rendering HTML in my head.